# I (have) had a rabbit for six years

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, present-simple

> 1. I've had a rabbit for six years.
> 2. I have a rabbit for six years.
> 3. I've cared a rabbit for six years.
> 4. I am caring a rabbit for six years.

Which tense should I use? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only 1. is correct. It states that you have been in possession of a rabbit for the past six years - and you are still in possession of it.

No 2. Is not correct. You can say:

> > I have a rabbit

but if you want to indicate for how long and you still have it, you have to use the present perfect: *have had*

If you no longer have the rabbit, you would say:

> > I had the rabbit for six years.

If you are looking after a rabbit, you are *caring for it*.

No 3. would be correct if you inserted the preposition *for*.

In no 4. you are either:

> > caring for a rabbit

or you:

> > have been caring for a rabbit for six years